# Приложения баз данных. Паттерны проектирования.

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, sql-server

Здравствуйте! Есть небольшая база данных, допустим, библиотеки. Какие паттерны проектирования стоило бы использовать? Какие правила стоит учитывать при проектировании базы данных и самого приложения? Стоит ли использовать паттерн MVP и какая выгода будет от этого? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Так а что ты пмсать собрался? Сайт? MVP это для юзер-интерфейса, а если твоя небольшая библиотека это пара книг на полке так можно и ввобще без патерном обойтись

Comment: использовать паттерны только для наличия использования паттернов - глупо

Comment: UI есть у меня. Цель  - научиться правильно проектировать приложения баз данных.
В своем вопросе я спрашиваю какая выгода  будет от использования MVP? Ведь Presenter должен преобразовывать данные модели для вида и наоборот, но в моем случае  почти ничего не надо преобразовывать.

Comment: @Flash `MVP` - это `client-side,` а не `server-side` паттерн. Вы можете применить его *(если уже не применяете)* в реализации своего `UI`, но к серверной части он не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: > Есть небольшая база данных, допустим, библиотеки

К датабазным продуктам MS традиционно прилагается пример - б/д издательства Northwind. На него смотрели?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как сказали в уточнениях, паттерн MVP действительно не имеет отношение к БД. Он скорее имеет отношение к интерфейсной части (client-side).

Я бы сказал, что самое главное правило, которого стоит придерживаться при разработке приложений, которые обращаются к БД, это трехслойная архитектура: UI - Business Logic - DB. В самом тупом случае, слой DB у вас может представлять собой набор хелперов для работы с БД.

В частности, отмечу некоторые важные моменты:

- все прямые обращения к БД должны быть только в слое DB, никаких прямых вызовов к БД, разбросанных по всему коду
- все обращения к слою DB должны исходить только из слоя BL, в UI не должно быть прямых вызовов кода из слоя DB

В остальном, реально не имеет значения (особенно в небольшом проекте), как у вас будет организовано получение и сохранение данных: тупые датасеты, ORM или что-то еще.

Существует несколько распространенных паттернов для работы с данными, однако их применение также не очень критично (и уж точно не стоит применять их ради самого факта применения, о чем говорили выше). Главное — обособить код для работы с базой, это уже избавит вас от множества проблем.

Ниже список некоторых паттернов для работы с БД:

http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/repository.html

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Access_Object

http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/table-data-gateway.html

http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/row-data-gateway.html

http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/active-record.html -- тут я готов спорить, предпочитаю иметь тупые объекты ([DTO](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/data-transfer-object.html), только данные) плюс классы, которые отвечают за загрузку/сохранение

http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/data-mapper.html

Comment: Спасибо за хороший, развернутый ответ.
И еще хотел бы узнать нужно ли выносить Data Access Layer в отдельный проект( но в этом же решении) .

Comment: Да. По многим причинам. Например, так потом легче можно отслеживать, что никто напрямую не обращается из слоя UI к слою DB.